# Profile picture does not update after form submitted

Tags: php, profile, updating

The below code allows a user on my site to update their profile picture and personal description using a POST method form.  The showprofile function displays their picture after it has been uploaded.

However, the problem is that after they have uploaded a new picture by clicking submit on the form, the old picture still appears on this page. The new picture does not show up until the page is refreshed.  I am trying to get the new picture to show up right away, after the form has been submitted.

```
<?php // Example 21-8: profile.php
include_once 'header.php';

if (!$loggedin) die();

echo "<div class='main'><h3>Your Profile</h3>";

if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $text = sanitizeString($_POST['text']);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);

    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles
        WHERE user='$user'")))
         queryMysql("UPDATE profiles SET text='$text' where user='$user'");
    else queryMysql("INSERT INTO profiles VALUES('$user', '$text')");
}
else
{
    $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row  = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $text = stripslashes($row[1]);
    }
    else $text = "";
}

$text = stripslashes(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text));

if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']))
{
    $saveto = "$user.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
    $typeok = TRUE;

    switch($_FILES['image']['type'])
    {
        case "image/gif":   $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;
        case "image/jpeg":  // Both regular and progressive jpegs
        case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;
        case "image/png":   $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;
        default:            $typeok = FALSE; break;
    }

    if ($typeok)
    {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);

        $max = 100;
        $tw  = $w;
        $th  = $h;

        if ($w > $h && $max < $w)
        {
            $th = $max / $w * $h;
            $tw = $max;
        }
        elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
        {
            $tw = $max / $h * $w;
            $th = $max;
        }
        elseif ($max < $w)
        {
            $tw = $th = $max;
        }

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
        imageconvolution($tmp, array(array(-1, -1, -1),
            array(-1, 16, -1), array(-1, -1, -1)), 8, 0);
        imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);
    }
}

showProfile($user);

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h3>Enter or edit your details and/or upload an image</h3>
<textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br />
_END;
?>

Image: <input type='file' name='image' size='14' maxlength='32' />
<input type='submit' value='Save Profile' />
</form></div><br /></body></html>
```

The showProfile function works as follows (it is included in the header.php file)

```
function showProfile($user)
{
    if (file_exists("$user.jpg"))
        echo "<img src='$user.jpg' align='left' />";

    $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it's being cached?

Comment: try `echo "<img src='".$user.".jpg?".date("U")."' align='left' />";` as cache killer..

Comment: btw i just so hope this "example" is not used to learn anybody php coding.... this is very bad coding style.

Comment: Your DB code is utterly horrendous. You have absolutely NO error handling and simply assume everything will always succeed.

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can introduce error handling. This is my first attempt at coding, so I am very eager to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possibly because of cache...

you should try this:

```
echo "<img src='{$user}.jpg?".time()."' align='left' />";
```